# CoreData Sum Performance

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, core-data, sum

I have some theoretical question to ask about *Core Data and sum* function.

I try to sum values from *Core Data* table with three ways.

1. fetch all and use expression to sum it up :

   ```
   NSArray * array1 = [self getAll:self.managedObjectContext];
   int sum = [[array1 valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.sum"] intValue];
   ```
2. fetch all and use for loop:

   ```
   int sum2 = 0;
   NSArray * array2 = [self getAll:self.managedObjectContext];

   for (Test * t in array2) {
       sum2 = sum2 + [t.sum intValue];
   }
   ```
3. let Core Data sum it.

   ```
   NSArray * array = [self getAllGroupe:self.managedObjectContext];
   NSDictionary * i = [array objectAtIndex:0];
   id j = [i objectForKey:@"sum"];

   (NSArray *)getAllGroupe:(NSManagedObjectContext*)Context{

       NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
       NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Test"  
                                      inManagedObjectContext:Context];

       NSExpressionDescription* ex = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
       [ex setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"@sum.sum"]];
       [ex setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
       [ex setName:@"sum"];


       [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:ex, nil]];
       [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType ];


       NSError *error;
       [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
       NSArray *fetchedObjects = [Context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

   return fetchedObjects;
   }
   ```

surprisingly the

1. way was the slowest (`for 1.000.000 data --> 19.2 s`), the
2. way was faster (`for 1.000.000 data --> 3.54 s`) and the
3. way was the fastest (`for 1.000.000 data --> 0.3 s`)

**Why is this?**

If I understand right even core data need to go through all `1.000.000` datas and sum it. Is this because use more cores if there are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No CoreData doesn't do the summing on it's own - it delegates that to it's backing sqllite database which is optimized for things like that.
Basically CoreData sends a `select SUM(sum) from table;` to it's db and it's performed there.

Comment: Do you know why is the 1. way slower than 2.-one?

Comment: @MarkoZadravec do you execute 1 and 2 in that order on the same context?

Comment: I assume that 1 is slower than 2 due because direct property access is probably fast then property access via key value coding