# CoreData sum in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a CoreData entity `Transaction` with a decimal `amount` attribute. I want to get the sum of all amounts filtered by a predicate.
Altohugh there are solutions [using loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344756/how-to-sum-a-double-attribute-from-coredata-in-swift) I want to do it directly in CoreData [because of performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720695/coredata-sum-performance) (and understanding `NSExpression`).

---

The following code works as expected but, as I said, is not what I am looking for

```swift
// Easy way: Fetch all and use `value(forKeyPath:)`
let transactionFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: CoreDateWrapper.Entity.Transaction)

var results: [NSManagedObject] = []

do {
    results = try wrapper.context.fetch(transactionFetch)
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

print((results as NSArray).value(forKeyPath: "@sum.\(CoreDateWrapper.Attribute.amount)") as! Decimal)
```

Now I want to use `NSExpression`, but the fetch result always is an empty array.

```
// Setup the expression and expression-description
let amountExpression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: CoreDateWrapper.Attribute.amount)
let sumExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [amountExpression])
let sumDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
sumDescription.expression = sumExpression
sumDescription.expressionResultType = .decimalAttributeType
sumDescription.name = "sum"

// Setup the fetchRequest to only get the sum.
// I expect a dictionary as a result instead of a `NSManagedObject`
let sumFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName: CoreDateWrapper.Entity.Transaction)
sumFetch.propertiesToFetch = [sumDescription]
sumFetch.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

// Fetch the sum
var sumResult: [String: Decimal]? = nil
do {
    let array = try wrapper.context.fetch(sumFetch)
       if let res = array.first as? [String: Decimal] {
        sumResult = res
    } else {
        print("Wrong type for result")
    }

} catch {
    print("Error fetching result: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

// Output the sum
if let sum = sumResult?["sum"] {
    print("Total: \(sum)")
}
```

This always prints *Wrong type for result* because `array` is empty.

Comment: Your code, minus the core data wrapper stuff, works perfectly for me. I made a super simple test project with a Transaction entity and a single amount property.

Comment: Is there any data added to your core data entity. Use a SQLite app to view the data and see if your underlying table actually has any data.

Comment: @jrturton The code is from a Playground I uploaded [here](https://gist.github.com/jlsiewert/645253e525c713fb7cba0b6d2dd1ed44). Unfortunately that one does not work.

Comment: Two problems with your playground: 1. it's using an in-memory store, and these don't work with NSExpressionDescriptions (you get an exception running in an app, but it seems to be swallowed in the playground. 2. Switching to an SQLite store (which presumably is what you'd be doing in real life to see any benefits of this) seems to have issues saving in a playground (saving throws errors, and the expression can only work on the database on disk) even using the shared data folder. It seems like playgrounds, unfortunately, kind of suck for core data.

Comment: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5287242985635840 for NSExpressionDescription and in-memory stores

Comment: @jrturton So a bug/ undocumented behaviour. Thanks a lot!